# Ubuntu and windows dual boot problem

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I recently installed ubuntu on my windows pc and everything worked fine and i was using ubuntu since i installed it and everytime i restart my computer it would bring me an option to choose from ubuntu and windows boot manager...and now i choose to open windows and when i restart again there is no option anymore i couldnt go back to ubuntu again.I tried enabling boot menu options on windows cmd but it just gave me an option to choose from windows versions. Is there anyway i can fix this?

Comment: If UEFI which it should be, can you use UEFI one time boot key and see the ubuntu entry? Chroot as in link above is one alternative, there may be others. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing the GRUB boot manager anymore before it boots into windows, there are a couple things you could try. The first and easiest to make sure GRUB is still there would be to spam the down arrow while booting and it should interrupt the boot sequence so you can see what boot options you have.

If GRUB no longer exists after installing windows or you've replaced it with the windows bootloader, you can try putting GRUB back on the MBR.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows